# Excel overtime formula based on cell as criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have simplified this as much as I can:

I would like to keep track of when overtime is being worked and by who.

[image: sample]

So in the sample, I have four employees over a period of five days working hours both above and below their contracted daily hours.

In the outlined cells I want to return how much time each employee worked beyond their contracted daily hours and how many hours employees worked beyond their contracted hours on each day. I am not interested in days where less hours were worked.

I hope this makes a bit more sense and many thanks to those who have aided me so far.

Comment: You could try =IF(statement, true, false)... https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2

Comment: Thanks, Dave. I'm probably being a bit slow, but I'm not really having any luck with that. Would you be able to provide an example of how I could use the if statement to sum only the hours above the contracted amount?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You wrote `Column C should have a total of...` Erm, how does a column have a total? A cell can have a total! Did you mean `C4`?

Comment: I will attempt to update more coherently this evening, thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with e.g. `SUMPRODUCT`:

- Total overtime by employee:
  `=SUMPRODUCT((D2:H2>C2)*(D2:H2-C2))`
- Total overtime by day:
  `=SUMPRODUCT((D2:D5>$C$2:$C$5)*(D2:D5-$C$2:$C$5))`

The logic is the same for both: first part check which employee / day has overtime, then sum those employees / days.

Alternatively you can use this formula too (this to be entered to D6):
`=SUM(IF(D2:D5>$C$2:$C$5,D2:D5-$C$2:$C$5,0))`
It is an array formula (need to press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after it) and also a bit longer, but probably better shows the logic of the formula.

[image]

Comment: That's great! I'm working with more complex data than this and a few more elements, but couldn't see what I'd done wrong. I simply started again with your formulae and it worked first time; thank you very much!